# How to exclude weekends in Kusto query?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

Is there a way to exclude weekends between two dates using existing Kusto commands?  I cannot find the right function in here https://kusto.azurewebsites.net/docs/queryLanguage/query-essentials/readme.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `| where dayofweek(timestamp) < 6` to exclude Saturday and Sunday from your query. Please refer to [dayofweek() doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dayofweekfunction).

Comment: This does not work, it includes Sunday. See below.

Answer (score 9):

I think Dmitry's comment might be out of date as it does not work. 0th index represents Sunday, and 6th index represents Saturday. A more specific working example to exclude weekends would be the following:

```
| where dayofweek(Timestamp) != time(6.00:00:00)
| where dayofweek(Timestamp) != time(0.00:00:00)
```

Which can be further condensed if desired.

Comment: example condensation `|extend weekday = dayofweek(<yourTimeField>) | where weekday != 0d and weekday != 6d`

Comment: another version `dayofweek(Timestamp) between (1d .. 5d)`

Answer (score 5):

Deriving from Void.Massive answer.

To improve readability, I just created variables for Saturday/Sunday, as I don't use this logic that often, or if I am sharing, I wanted to make this logic a little easier on the reader.

```
let Saturday = time(6.00:00:00);
let Sunday = time(0.00:00:00);
//
| where dayofweek(Timestamp) != Saturday
| where dayofweek(Timestamp) != Sunday
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option is to do `!in` check.

```
let T = datatable(timestamp: datetime)
[
   datetime("2022-04-03"), // Sunday
   datetime("2022-04-04"), // Monday
   datetime("2022-04-05"), // Tuesday
   datetime("2022-04-06"), // Wednesday
   datetime("2022-04-07"), // Thursday
   datetime("2022-04-08"), // Friday
   datetime("2022-04-09"), // Saturday
   datetime("2022-04-10"), // Sunday
];
T 
// 0d = Sunday, 6d = Saturday
| where dayofweek(timestamp) !in (0d, 6d)
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone already pointed out, Dmitry's comment is out of date and does not work. Other answers here are better.
However I think that a different but better way to do this nowadays is to add this condition to a where clause:

```
and dayofweek(timestamp) between (1d .. 5d)
```

Where 1d is Monday and 5d is Friday